# PhoneGap...iOS...my app's "documents and data" keeps getting larger and larger

Tags: ios, cordova

So we have built an app that is almost completely dynamic.

You build the content on a website and then the app pulls the content that the administrators created for the user using a REST api.

The content can be videos, images, rich text, or form controls. All of this is stored externally on our servers...not locally.

We have hundreds of pages (kinda like a choose your own adventure).

We cache some stuff...usually about 3 - 5 pages at a time, but we don't store any content locally...we save to our server only.

So we noticed something weird while testing...when we go to Settings/General/Usage/Manage Storage we noticed our app keeps getting bigger and bigger. If we drill down into the app we can see that the app itself is only 15 megs, but as you use the app it can grow to over 100 Megs.

When we close the app out completely it will shrink down by about 20%, but somehow the app is keeping stuff and I am not sure why.

Does iOS cache things on its own? Is there a way to clear that on exit?

Again, we are purposefully not saving anything...but something obviously is.

Any thoughts?

**Update**
So I was asked more about the tech...it is a PhoneGap app that uses JQuery ajax calls to hit a .Net Web API project.

I don't mind caching while the app is running, but when the app has been closed by the user...why is there data being stored?

Thanks,
David

Comment: Good question, I have noticed the same thing with my app

Comment: as you give no information about how do you load your external content, if you use jQuery, you can set the cache to false $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); to make the ajax calls not to cache the responses.

Comment: I updated my post to include a bit more about the tech.

Comment: Hello David.. i was wondering if you solved this issue? I have the exact same problem on my cordova (with ionic 2) app. I don't save anything on the client side... i even dont cache http requests. This happens only on ios. I guess that by default ios caches images?( i display alot on my app)

Comment: @tubu13 Unfortunately we never did...  the app, for heavy users, just used a lot of data...

Comment: @David I Found out that cordova plugins like camera and image picker, are copying the image/video before returning it to the application.. So for example every time the user pick a image the app data increases. So the solution will be to delete the image after using it. Maybe that can be a solution for you aswell